# How to append new line to the list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, dimensional

I'm trying to present dimensional list in one column. I'm doing it in function so I want to append everything to new list. There is a problem. I cannot append new line to the list. I cannot use join because I' am operating on the lists not string so I got the error.My output should be the same as code :

```
a = [[1], [2], [3]]
for elem in a:
    print(elem)
    print(" ")
Out =
[1]
 
[2]
 
[3]
```

The idea is that it should be in list. I want to get list and after that return it in the function(This is only a small part of code but necessary to solve my exercise). My desire ouput is to get list for example named b.

```
b = [[1]

[2]

[3]]
```

After that return in the function. I cannot use this solution because I got the wrong ouput.

```
def exerc():
    a = [[1], [2], [3]]
    for elem in a:
        print(elem)
        print(" ")
print(exerc())
```

Out =
[1]

[2]

[3]

None
I dont want to have this "none"

Comment: There is no return in your function.

Comment: Because there was no idea to insert it. What it should return? I cannot create list so I cannot return this list

Comment: What do you mean you can't create list?  You create a list with this line `a = [[1], [2], [3]]`

Answer (score 0):

Based on what's in your question, this will do what you're looking for:

```py
a = [[1], [2], [3]]
print('[')
for elem in a:
    print(elem)
    print(" ")
print(']')
```

Comment: I know that I can do it like this. But I want to append this data to the list and return in later in function. So I want to return the list so I cannot use your solution

Comment: @New_stud then can you edit your question to explain what you actually want

Comment: Sorry, I did it now, you can  read it

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
print(f"[{elem}]", end=" ")
```